# MIPS Floating Point Multiplication

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips, floating-point-precision

I am new to programming in MIPS and am having trouble understanding how I can multiply two floats after reading them in from the user. How do I get the argument into a single precision floating point number? When I run the program, it prints the result as 0.0 instead of the number multiplied by the constant. Can someone explain to me why it is printing 0.0 instead of the correct number?

```
.data

prompt: .asciiz "Enter the amount: "

newline: .asciiz "\n"

float1: .float  0.0

const:  .float  121.28      

.text

.globl main

main:   


li  $v0, 4      #calls print_string code 4
la  $a0, prompt #pointer to string
syscall

#get amount from user
li  $v0, 6      #call read_float code 6
syscall
la  $a0, float1 #loads address of float1
l.s $f1, 0($a0) #a0 --> float1
la  $a1, const  #loads address of const
l.d $f2, 0($a1) #a1 --> float2

#calculates 
mul.s   $f1, $f1, $f2   #f1 = f1*f2

#prints resulting amount
li  $v0, 2      #calls print_float code 2   
syscall

#continual loop
li  $v0, 4      #calls print_string code 4
la  $a0, newline    #pointer to string
syscall

j main          #jumps to beginning of main
```

Comment: If you think a little it should be obvious that the `read_float` can't magically read the input into `float1`. As such, you are multiplying with zero. If you consult the manual, you will see that `read_float` returns the value in `$f0`. Also, learn to use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It print 0 'cause you multiplied for 0.. after you call for an input you don't store it (`s.s $f0, float1 #store the input`), after that if you want to print in mips you have to say what.. I stored the result of the operation in float1 again(`s.s $f1, float1   #store multiplied float`) an then printed whit the proper call `l.s $f12, float1  #print multiplied float`
Remember to use the proper register for the system call function
That's the working code main

```
main:   


li  $v0, 4      #calls print_string code 4
la  $a0, prompt #pointer to string
syscall

#get amount from user
li  $v0, 6      #call read_float code 6
syscall

s.s $f0, float1 #store the input

la  $a0, float1 #loads address of float1
l.s $f1, 0($a0) #a0 --> float1
la  $a1, const  #loads address of const
l.d $f2, 0($a1) #a1 --> float2

#calculates 
mul.s   $f1, $f1, $f2   #f1 = f1*f2

s.s $f1, float1   #store multiplied float

#prints resulting amount
li  $v0, 2      #calls print_float code 2   
l.s $f12, float1  #print multiplied float
syscall

#continual loop
li  $v0, 4      #calls print_string code 4
la  $a0, newline    #pointer to string
syscall

j main
```